# Symmetric subspace dimension of Hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, quantum-mechanics, hermitian-matrices

Is there a general formula for the dimension of the symmetric subspace of any Hermitian matrix?

The closest concept I was able to find is the [following classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_symmetric_space).

[image]

Is the complex dimension what I need?

Context of my question:
I am taking the following screengrab from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.12724.pdf).

[image]

In the second from the bottom line, the author mentions "We may restrict to the symmetric subspace of this Hilbert space". Then, he defines D(N, n_bos) which is the dimension of the space. I am trying to understand how he determined the following approximation.

[image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @AnneBauval, thanks I have added little more info.

Comment: I think that table is _not_ at all what you want: it's about "hermitian symmetric spaces", which do not have much to do with a given hermitian matrix. Can you clarify what you mean by "symmetric subspace of hermitian matrix"?

Comment: @paulgarrett, I have added more context to my question.

Comment: Ah, so it's "symmetric subspace of Hilbert space (with extra data?)", but could you tell what "symmetric subspace of Hilbert space" means for you? Or is that the question, actually?

Comment: @paulgarrett, In Section 1.1, the author has said "A symmetric tensor is one that is invariant under permutation of its indices." So, I am assuming a symmetric subspace means the collection of all points in a Hilbert space, where the tensor at that point is symmetric.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I see... one quibble: I doubt that there's any "tensor at that point" in a Hilbert space. And, then, definitely, there is no serious connection to "hermitian symmetric spaces" (your first cited thing)... Rather, I think you intend to ask about an estimate for the dimension of the $S_n$-invariant tensors/vectors in the $n$-fold tensor power $\bigotimes^n \mathbb R^N$ with the natural action by permuting coordinates. That tensor power/product _is_ a repn space for the symmetric group $S_n$, and decomposes into irreducibles, etc...

Comment: @paulgarrett, I think you are correct. What is the best way I can determine the dimension?